# Use duration variable as label selector

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a variable `latency_target = 5s`. How use it in a PromQL query as a histogram label selector:

```
sum(rate(histogram{le="$latency_target"}[$interval]))
```

This does not work, dues to `s` suffix. I tried to use `duration` function, but it does not work

Comment: Couldn't you just drop `s` part of your variable value?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to dynamically compute that label. I can enter `5`, I can enter `$latency_target`, but I don't know how use anything more sophisticated like `duration(latency_target)`

Comment: Variable `latency_target` is a dynamically computed one? If so, [edit] question and add a description of that. Also please clarify what `duration` are you referring to, because I'm not aware of such a function in Prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

If you want calculating the percentage of requests with durations not exceeding the given threshold (aka SLI / SLA / SLO or the inverse of [histogram_quantile()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_quantile)), from [Prometheus histogram](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram), then there are bad and good news:

- The bad news is that Prometheus doesn't provide such a functionality :(
- The good news is that other Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on - [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/stargazers) - provides [histogram_share()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_share) function for calculating the SLI / SLA from Prometheus histograms. For example, the following query returns the percentage (on the range `0..1`) of queries with durations not exceeding 1.5 seconds over the last 10 minutes:

```
histogram_share(1.5s, sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[10m])) by (le))
```

You can freely substitute the first arg to `histogram_share()` function with Grafana variable, which contains [Prometheus-compatible duration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations), as well as the lookbehind window in square brackets for the [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) function:

```
histogram_share($latency_target, sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[$interval])) by (le))
```

This query should work correctly for any Prometheus-compatible durations behind `latency_target` and `$interval` variables.